# MySQL "Unknown Column in On Clause"

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mysql-error-1054

I have the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT posts.id,  posts.name,  LEFT(posts.content, 400),  posts.author,  posts.date, users.display_name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag ORDER BY tag_linking.pid ASC SEPARATOR ",") update_tags
FROM posts, tag_linking, tags
INNER JOIN `users`
ON posts.author=users.id;
WHERE tag_linking.pid = posts.id 
  AND tags.id = tag_linking.tid 
ORDER BY posts.date DESC
```

Which, was you can see, connects three tables etc. etc. Anyway, the problem is that it gives an error:

```
ERROR CODE:
SQL Error (1054): Unknown column 'posts.author' in 'on clause'
```

even though this simpler query used on another page works:

```
SELECT posts.id,  posts.name,  LEFT(posts.content, 400),  posts.author,  posts.date, users.display_name FROM `posts`
INNER JOIN `users`
ON posts.author=users.id
```

Does anyone have thoughts as to why this is occuring? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Any reason you're mixing 'lazy join' with 'explicit join' syntax?

Comment: @MarcB Probably the same reason I just stumbled into this one--updating a query that used a lazy join and now requires a different explicit join.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

because your mix join syntax

[`From Mysql`*<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

> However, the precedence of the comma operator is less than of INNER
>   JOIN, CROSS JOIN, LEFT JOIN, and so on. **If you mix comma joins with
>   the other join types when there is a join condition, an error of the
>   form Unknown column 'col_name' in 'on clause' may occur**. Information
>   about dealing with this problem is given later in this section.

the solution is:

> To allow the join to be processed, group the first two tables
>   explicitly with parentheses so that the operands for the ON clause are
>   (t1,t2) and t3:
>
> **SELECT * FROM (t1, t2) JOIN t3 ON (t1.i1 = t3.i3);**
>
> **Alternatively**, avoid the use of the comma operator and use JOIN
>   instead:
>
> **SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 JOIN t3 ON (t1.i1 = t3.i3);**

Answer (score 1):

is it that semi colon you have `ON posts.author=users.id;`

Answer (score 0):

Giving an alias to your tables in `from` clause and surrounding them with parentheses would make it work. But mixing joins is still a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

It simply says that author does not exist in post table. either a spelling mistake??