# MySQL - Column not found despite not being referenced in join

Tags: mysql, join

I have MySQL JOIN in roughly the following format:

```
SELECT DISTINCT employees.empl_id,
                employees.name,
                departments.dep_id,
                departments.name,
                buildings.id         AS building_id,
                buildings.address    AS building_address
                buildings.department AS building_department
FROM employees
     LEFT JOIN employees USING (empl_id)
     LEFT JOIN departments USING (dep_id)
     LEFT JOIN buildings
            ON buildings.department = departments.dep_id
```

When I run this query I get the error:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 1: Unknown column 'MyDB.employees.dep_id' in 'on clause'
```

Even tough the column `dep_id` really does not exists in employees, I never reference `employees.dep_id` in the JOIN, and `dep_id` is a column of `departments` and not employees!!

Can this be due to mixing the `USING` and `ON` clause?

This JOIN is part of a script I wrote which was done using MySQL version > 5, and no errors occurred. I am adapting the script to work with an older version of MySQL and ran into this error. `mysql --version` yields:

```
mysql  Ver 14.7 Distrib 4.1.22, for pc-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 4.3
```

I read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483421/mysql-unknown-column-in-on-clause) but it did not help me. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You would be best served to *forget* about the existence of `USING` and stick with `ON` for joins.  Similarly, never use `DISTINCT` without a specific and deliberate reason to do so.  It often masks illogical or invalid queries and can harm the performance of properly-written queries when it is used but not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that you are doing that join here:

```
LEFT JOIN departments USING (dep_id)
```

means

```
LEFT JOIN departments ON employees.dep_id = departments.dep_id
```

and this is what is causing your error.

Comment: I changed all my `USING` clauses into the equivalent `ON` clauses and it fixed the problem. Thank you!